# Omit item from Sum SQL

Tags: sql, having

I'm very new to programming and SQL, I can't figure this one out, perhaps I haven't learned the concept yet, but I'm hoping you can help me. Sorry if it's too easy and boring.

```
/*2.37 Write an SQL statement to display the WarehouseID and the sum of
QuantityOnHand,grouped by WarehouseID. Omit all SKU items that have 3 or more items 
on hand   from the sum, and name the sum TotalItemsOnHandLT3 and display the results 
in descending order of TotalItemsOnHandLT3.*/

SELECT WarehouseID, SUM(QuantityOnHand) AS TotalItemsOnHandLT3
FROM INVENTORY
GROUP BY WarehouseID
HAVING COUNT(WarehouseID) >= 3
ORDER BY TotalItemsOnHandLT3 DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Omit all SKU items that have 3 or more items on hand from the sum*", sounds more like :

```
FROM INVENTORY WHERE QuantitiyOnHand < 3
```

rather than :

```
HAVING COUNT(WarehouseID) >= 3
```

Comment: that's it, I should've mentioned that the reason why I asked is bc the previous question just asked for the sum without the omitting items section, and whatever I was doing, I kept getting the same answer for both, so I knew that something was wrong with the omitting items part. I thought I had tried your solution, but I guess I hadn't. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`INVENTORY` is the list of products (`SKU` = Stock Keeping Unit = Individual Product Stored in the warehouse) where every product has a `WarehouseID`. This `warehouseID` presumably determines where the product is stored.

By **Omit all SKU items**, it asks you to only display those products that are stored in minimum 3 places in the warehouse. This can be done with the `having` clause,

```
 HAVING COUNT(WarehouseID) >= 3
```

I do not know the structure and data of your `INVENTORY` table, but simply put, Consider your data is like this:

```
SKUID  WareHouseID  QuantityOnHand
1      1            10
1      2            10
2      1            10
1      3            5
2      2            20
```

In the above case, Product = 1 (SKUID), is stored in 3 different warehouses whereas product 2 is stored in 2 warehouses. Hence,

```
SKUID  COUNT(WareHouseID)  SUM(QuantityOnHand)
1      3                   25
2      2                   30
```

In this case, your query will only "Omit" product 1, and not the product 2.

Answer (score 0):

Its says Omit, they why

```
HAVING COUNT(WarehouseID) >= 3
```

and not

```
HAVING COUNT(WarehouseID) < 3
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).